# how to limit a text or div inside a parent tag

Tags: html, css

```
body
{
width:1024px;
height:600px;
}

#footer
{
margin-top:800px;
}
```

My question is there a way of setting some property in the parent tag body , to limit the child inside that tag (i dont want footer outside the body box model) only even if we SET HIGHER VALUE than parent tag body.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is not a good coding practice. in this case you should try limiting the target element from the #footer itself. this might [help](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Answer (score 1):

While you should avoid to set a higher value in a child tag, in case it is, you more likely want to use `overflow:hidden;` who basically hides anything that is "out of bound".

See this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GMPz2/) for an example.